# How to change interval in timepicker yii

Tags: php, yii

I have tried following.

```
<?php echo $form->timepickerRow($model, 'overtime_two', array('prepend'=>'<i class="icon-time"
style="cursor:pointer;margin-top:0px"></i>', 'options'=>array('format'=>'hh:mm:ss',
showMeridian'=>false, 'minuteGrid'=>5, ), ) ); ?>
```

But without any result.

Comment: what is timepickerRow ?

Comment: it is work like date/time picker.  see following url.  http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/